# Recommended Wiki that can be deployed on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm looking for recommendations for a Wiki that can be deployed on Heroku.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess [Instiki](http://github.com/parasew/instiki) should work fine. But I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a guide here http://blazingcloud.net/2010/06/18/deploying-a-redmine-wiki-to-heroku/ to install Redmine wiki.

Answer (score 1):

someone already made an [instiki-heroku](https://github.com/lazzarello/instiki-heroku) build on github
i deployed it last night in a matter of minutes